# Object_ID does not detect the recently created or dropped tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am having issue with working of Object_ID to detect if the table already exists.
It works fine the first iteration and allows to create the required tables properly.
But if executed again, it still thinks/sees that tables are not created and tries to create the table and then SQL Server gives the error that tables already exist.
SQL Server version 2008

**Code**

```
--Alter Proc spCreateCustomerChartTables
--As
Begin
Declare
@mycursorMARKET Cursor,
@mycursorCUSTOMER Cursor, 
@MarketNameEnglish nchar(30),
@CustomerID nchar(10),
@DDate date,
@textdate as nchar(12),
@tableName nchar(100),
@sqlcmd as nvarchar(500)


    Set @DDate = GETDATE()

    Set @mycursorMARKET = Cursor for Select Distinct MarketNameEnglish From dbo.tableMarketName Order by MarketNameEnglish ASC
    Open @mycursorMARKET
    Fetch Next From @mycursorMARKET Into @MarketNameEnglish
    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin

        Set @mycursorCUSTOMER = Cursor for Select Distinct CustomerID From dbo.CustomerEmployeeDetail Order by CustomerID ASC
        Open @mycursorCUSTOMER
        Fetch Next From @mycursorCUSTOMER Into @CustomerID
        While @@FETCH_STATUS =0
        Begin
            Set @textdate = cast(@DDate as NCHAR(12))
            Set @tableName = RTrim(@MarketNameEnglish) + '_' + RTrim(@CustomerID) + '_' + RTrim(@textdate )


            If OBJECT_ID(@tableName , 'U') IS Not Null
            --IF Not EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
            --  WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName )
                Begin
                Print 'Table Does Not Exist'
                Set @sqlcmd = 'Select * Into ' + RTrim(@tableName) + ' From BlankChart'
                Set @sqlcmd = RTRIM(@sqlcmd)
                Set @sqlcmd = REPLACE (@sqlcmd, '-', '_')
                Exec(@sqlcmd)
                End
            Else 
                Begin
                Print 'Table Exists'
                Set @sqlcmd = 'Drop Table ' + @tableName 
                Set @sqlcmd = RTRIM(@sqlcmd)
                Set @sqlcmd = REPLACE (@sqlcmd, '-', '_')
                Exec(@sqlcmd)
                End


            --Print @sqlcmd --Create chart tables here
            Fetch Next From @mycursorCUSTOMER Into @CustomerID
        End
        --Print @MarketNameEnglish
        Fetch Next From @mycursorMARKET Into @MarketNameEnglish
    End

Close @mycursorMARKET
Deallocate @mycursorMARKET
Close @mycursorCUSTOMER
Deallocate @mycursorCUSTOMER

End
```

Comment: The output of this line *** If OBJECT_ID(@tableName , 'U') IS Not Null *** remains same irrespective of actually the table exists or not. If it true 1st time, it remains true in every iteration. If it is false first time, it remains false in every iteration.

Comment: That SQL looks **very** open to injection. What are you actually trying to achieve here? If `OBJECT_ID` is saying the object doesn't have an ID, it doesn't exist; that much is certain. [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Also, how was `OBJECT_ID` provide the values of the recently **dropped** object..?

Comment: Your `IF` statement is the wrong way round. `OBJECT_ID(@tableName , 'U') ` will be not null if the table exists, and null if it does not, so you are effectively saying, if the table exists, select into it, else (if it does not exist) drop it. As an aside though, this seems like a massive code smell. Why on earth are you creating a new table for every customer, every day?

Comment: You should also always look to declare the simplest cursor possible. If you are only reading from the cursor, tell SQL server this and declare it as`READONLY`, if you are only moving forward in the cursor, tell SQL Server and declare it `FORWARD_ONLY`, if you are only using it locally, declare it as `LOCAL` etc. For more reading: [What impact can different cursor options have?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options)

Comment: @GarethD I changed the code to *** If OBJECT_ID(@tableName , 'U') IS Null ***. Now, when actually the table does not exist and I run the code, it creates the tables. Once the table is created, I run the code again. This time instead of dropping the table, it still thinks that tables are not created and tries to create it, thereby giving error  "There is already and object name ...." This happens only if I use the variable instead of hardcoded table.

Comment: @GarethD The reason why I am creating table everyday is because I want to fill this table using a trigger. This table is planned to store the data after some processing. If I try to process the data in run time when user requests the processed data, it takes too long to process it. I am ultra low level beginner in programming and this method might not be appropriate way to handle this situation. But I am trying to build a proof of concept for an app. So that I can explain it to a professional later, who can do it in appropriate way. This processed data will be deleted after 1 week.

Comment: @GarethD Thanks for your tip about using the cursor in appropriate manner. This is a new learning.

Comment: @Larnu The proof of concept that I am trying to build records data as per the user input with some set rules like size, sorting order, etc. These records are then processed to create final data that is to be used for analysis. This processed data is to be stored in these dynamically created tables. So I want to create a table only if it does not exist.

Comment: @Larnu I use customer id, market name & date to create a name for table. This name is stored in a variable "@tablename". This variable is then used to check whether the table exist or not. If not then create it. So I pass the tablename to Object_ID using the variable of datatype nchar.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is "inverted":

your `If OBJECT_ID(@tableName , 'U') IS Not Null` should be changed to `If OBJECT_ID(@tableName , 'U') IS Null`

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the mistake in my code. It had got nothing to do with Object_ID.
Actually the formating of variable @tablename was done incorrectly and at incorrect place. The dashes (-) of date in tablename were not replaced with underscore (_). This was causing the error.